# Visual Studio recover source file manually

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, recovery

I lost on of my ASP.NET usercontrol in Visual studio 2010
Is there any way to recover target file manually?
The UserControl is named billpay.ascx.
I saw some file with similar name in this directory: (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\negso.ui\b0ed5857\e612bf58)

They named as

- billpay.ascx.f1005316.compiled
- billpay.ascx.f1005316_CBMResult.ccu
- billpay.ascx.f1005316_CBMResult.compiled
- App_Web_billpay.ascx.f1005316.w4xcy81l.0.vb
- App_Web_billpay.ascx.f1005316.w4xcy81l.1.vb
- App_Web_billpay.ascx.f1005316.w4xcy81l.2.vb

Is there anyway to recover target file?
Auto recover window did not open for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same directory as you say, search for the DLL files and open them with an asp.net de-compiler like the "Net Reflector". You can then see the source code and get it back.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following path:

```
\…\My Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Backup Files\<projectname>.
```

Comment: thanks man, I also enjoy your posts in Barnamenevis.org. But it seems no way I should do my work again because that folder is empty.